# Need batch file code to replace filepath with cd-rom drive letter

Tags: batch-file

Here is the copy statement I have currently.

I am looking to replace the F: with %cdrom% so that this script will work no matter what computer it is used on.

```
XCOPY F:\*.* .\disk2\ /C /S /D /Y /I
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not easy to detect CD-ROM drive in batch files. You'd have to use some tools for this. Even if you have some tool that can successfully detect CD-ROM/harddisk/USB status, there still can be multiple CD-ROM drives or virtual drives.

One of the easiest ways to do this (although you can't rely on it): Trying to copy and delete a temporary file to D,E,F,G... until you get an error (this gives you the first read-only drive which often is the CD-ROM drive).

You should also think about asking the user for the drive letter or at least give him the possibility to define %CDROM%.

There are other ways to detect CD-ROM drives floating around in the net (f.e. [here](http://www.computing.net/answers/dos/how-to-find-cdrom-letter-in-batch-file/8766.html#)), but they are often only working with an particular OS and rely on tools like registry editors, so you should think about using some non-batch solution or an additional tool instead.

Comment: `wmic cdrom` gives you a list of CD ROM drives. No need for random write tries or querying the registry.

Comment: Wow, didn't know that - nice one!

Answer (score 1):

I just pieced together the following little script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1* delims= " %%x in ('wmic cdrom get drive^,name') do (
    if not [%%y]==[] (
        set /a count+=1
        set drive_!count!=%%x
        set drivename_!count!=%%y
    )
)

if %count%==0 goto error
if %count%==1 set cdrom=%drive_1%
if %count% GTR 1 call :more

if defined ERROR goto :eof

XCOPY %cdrom%\*.* .\disk2\ /C /S /D /Y /I 

goto :eof

:more
set ERROR=
set letters=
echo %count% CD ROM drives found
for /l %%x in (1,1,%count%) do (
    echo.  !drive_%%x! - !drivename_%%x!
    set letters=!letters!!drive_%%x:~0,1!
)
choice /C %letters% /M "Enter the drive letter to copy from" /N
if errorlevel 255 set ERROR=1
if not errorlevel 1 set ERROR=1
set cdrom=!drive_%errorlevel%!
goto :eof

:error
1>&2 echo No CD ROM drive found
goto :eof
```

Should be fairly straightforward. I'm getting a list of CD ROM drives with `wmic` and store their drive letters and captions. If there is only one CD ROM drive the selection is unambiguous, so copying can start right away, otherwise the user is prompted.